# Flutter - I want to show only first 2 Paragraphs

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a Big passage with like 8 Paragraphs. But I only want to show the first 2 paras.
Let's take the below example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla scelerisque et urna id porttitor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer vitae auctor diam. Curabitur ipsum turpis, porta sit amet lorem sit amet, ultricies gravida turpis. Mauris congue purus nec tortor laoreet, eu rutrum ligula egestas. Morbi ut magna sapien. Aliquam malesuada velit nec lorem ultricies facilisis. Praesent imperdiet porttitor sodales.

Proin vel arcu purus. Ut nulla lectus, mattis nec condimentum quis, vulputate ac lacus. Suspendisse potenti. Duis consectetur ante ac ultricies sagittis. Donec finibus tortor eu nibh volutpat, non tincidunt nibh malesuada. Nunc sit amet purus vel arcu facilisis facilisis. Pellentesque felis nunc, bibendum fringilla auctor a, varius sit amet nibh.

Maecenas scelerisque, lacus eu gravida fermentum, magna magna finibus urna, eu pulvinar nisl nisi sed velit. Sed in iaculis lacus, sed ornare ipsum. Fusce commodo risus quis arcu volutpat, vitae sollicitudin dolor pellentesque. Phasellus lacus quam, placerat eu lorem vitae, congue accumsan metus. Fusce ultricies vehicula tempus. Aenean a urna tempus, eleifend felis et, venenatis justo. Aliquam quis dapibus risus. Nunc gravida sodales metus, eget aliquet nunc vestibulum vitae. Donec semper finibus ex ac elementum. Maecenas sed nulla id tellus viverra tincidunt quis sed leo. Fusce quis condimentum elit. Donec ultricies imperdiet pulvinar. Nunc egestas quis leo eu cursus. Sed faucibus, enim non dictum commodo, velit felis maximus risus, ut hendrerit dui augue vel justo.
```

I am getting this data from an API. I only want to show the first 2 paragraphs starting with **Lorem ipsum** & **Proin vel** respectively.

I have no idea how to do this. I tried searching the web but did not find any useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p = text.split('\n\n').take(2);
```

or if it's needed to join into single string

```
var p = text.split('\n\n').take(2).join('\n\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

The Text Widget has the property of max lines you can use it to specify how many lines from a paragraph should be shown. And there is a text-overflow property that can help you get more control over it. Following is an example.

```
Text(
    "This is a long text",
     overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
     maxLines: 1,
     softWrap: false,
      ),
```